# Profiler tool for web service

Tags: web-services, profiler

I need a profiler that is able to measure performance of web service execition.

Our application has several layers and ideally I would like to be able to dive into each web service request and see how much time was spent in each layer (server, sql server, etc...)

Is there a tool that can help detect where are the bottlenecks ?

Is that something that can be done using VS Team System Test Edition ?

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I am a developer on the Visual Studio Profiler Team.

Visual Studio Test Edition does not have a profiler, but the following editions do:

- Visual Studio 2005 Development Edition, Team Suite
- Visual Studio 2008 Development Edition, Team Suite
- Visual Studio 2010 Premium, Ultimate

Currently, the VS Profiler is not capable of profiling across machines, but a new feature was introduced in VS2010: Tier Interaction Profiling.  Essentially, it will show you timing data for any ADO.NET database calls you make.

Additional resources:

- [Walkthrough: Using the Tier Interaction Profiler in Visual Studio Team System 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/habibh/archive/2009/06/30/walkthrough-using-the-tier-interaction-profiler-in-visual-studio-team-system-2010.aspx)
- [Multi-Tier Performance Analysis](http://blogs.msdn.com/profiler/archive/2009/12/28/multi-tier-performance-analysis.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is [dotTrace profiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html). it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have looked in perfmon?